# C++ code why so much and what does it mean? Can anyone explain. (I am a C# developer)

Tags: c#, c++-cli, windows-8.1

Am trying to learn a new language so any answers would help

Site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263168.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-6

Now have a look at the c# code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263168.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-6

The C# code is so simple.

I am a C# developer, trying learn the c++ application development for windows 8.

I have done some application development in C++ and java on a small scale

What I don't understand is why so many properties and codes are defined in the c++ code when they are not present in the C# code?

And, can anyone please explain this c++ code, and offer some pointers as to how to start c++ development for windows 8.

Comment: I'll admit that C++ has its niche, but it seems to me that for developing Windows 8 apps, you'd be better off sticking with C#.  There's not many reasons why I'd pick C++ over C#.  C++ is so much more complex than C#, and you don't get a lot of extra benefits with the extra complexity.

Comment: yes right but i am doing this for learning only please help

Comment: Your question fails to show your point.  Both links in fact are for C++ code.  The C# tab even shows C++ code :)  Use the [proper link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh986965.aspx) for the C# sample.  Now compare and check if your question still makes sense.

Comment: yea very unfriendly of the site to display c++ code even when you click c# tab!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short/layman's version is that in the C# (actually, all .NET) world a lot of the code isn't necessary because it's already included in the [Base Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfa3fa08.aspx), the [Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4.aspx), or other thihgs that you get "for free" with .NET.

.NET was designed from the gound up to be easier to use.  Much of the code that you had to do manually in C, C++ an dother older languages is alreaqdy handled, either in the Base Class Library, or in the Common Language Runtime.  Microsoft designed .NET for Rapid Applicaiton Development - to make a language/toolkit that's easy for people to pick up on, and that included hiding a lot of the implementation details.

The longer/ more detailed answer, woud likely encompass at least one, if not several books.

However, there's a nice article here that gives a high-level overview of life before .NETand what .NET was designed to do:  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=680832